# Using overlapping values in two dataframes to extract another column of interest

Tags: r

I am trying to use a "DrugID" column found in two datasets to extract another value corresponding to that drugID value, ie. "Target." I essentially want to take df1 and add a column with the correct "Target" from df2.

Example of the df I am looking for:

Day DrugID Target ....

For example:

Dataframe 1:

[image]

Dataframe 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use images/screenshot in your question and these aren't reproducible.
If your dataframes are names say `df1` and `df2` you should have shared `dput(df1)` or data is bigger then `dput(head(df1, 10))` etc..

use this syntax

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% left_join(df2 %>% select(DrugID, Target), by ="DrugID" )
```

or in baseR

```
merge(df1, df2[,c(1, 3)], by = "DrugID")
```